# How to get URL of media clicked on in a QWebEnginePage, and all other media links on the page

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qmediaplayer

I can't compile my own Qt with proprietary codecs, let alone then compiling PyQt5 from this Qt build, so I have a workaround idea in order to be able to display these kind of media files ie h.264 on my browser (I assume I will still need to get licences etc). What I have thought of is to get all of the media links that are on the webpage, and put them into a `QMediaPlaylist`, and then select the correct video when one is clicked on the webpage.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
import sys

class Player(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,parent=None,*args,**kwargs):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)

    self._player = QMediaPlayer(self)
    self._player.setAudioRole(QAudio.VideoRole)
    
    self._playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    self._playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")))
    self._player.setPlaylist(self._playlist)

    self._videoWidget = VideoWidget(self)
    self._player.setVideoOutput(self._videoWidget)

    self._playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self._player.play()

    self.setCentralWidget(self._videoWidget)
    self.showMaximized()

class VideoWidget(QVideoWidget):
  def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
    QVideoWidget.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)

  def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape and self.isFullScreen():
      self.setFullScreen(False)
      event.accept()
      
    elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter and event.modifiers() == Qt.Key_Alt:
      self.setFullScreen(not self.isFullScreen())
      event.accept()
      
    else:
      super().keyPressEvent(event)

  def mouseDoubleClickEvent(event):
    self.setFullScreen(not self.isFullScreen())
    event.accept()

def exceptHook(self,e,v,t):
  sys.__excepthook__(e,v,t)

sys.excepthook = exceptHook
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = Player()
app.exec_()
```

In this example, there is only one .mp4 link in the media playlist for testing, where-as for my browser I would like to be able to add the URLs of all the media files of the webpage. When a video is clicked on the webpage, I would like to be able to locate the URL in the playlist, switch to the corresponding index, and then overlay the video widget onto the webpage, and play it. I don't know how to:

- Get all the media links of the webpage (not all are intercepted in `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` as some links are stored in tags in the mainframe website's html code)
- Get the clicked media's URL (need some sort of signal or event maybe?)
- Get a video's coordinate location on the page (and update it for scrolling etc)

I have tried using the `triggerAction` and intercepting the events, but there aren't any actions being made that allow me to get the clicked videos URL. I suppose I could get the webpage html with `.toHtml(callback)`, and maybe get the links from there by filtering with `beautifulSoup4`, but the `.toHtml` call is quite slow in my experience. I assume there is some Javascript I could run to get the video's coordinate locations (and maybe links) but I have no experience with Javascript.

Comment: Why don't you want or can you compile Qt WebEngine with the proprietary codecs?

Comment: I started trying to, but when i git cloned qt5, and tried to compile QtWebEngine, I had  `submodule initialized... no`, and also got an error about a `private_tests` object not being found (posted in my previous question). Furthermore to this, I realize that I don't really have the resources to compile QtWebEngine, with less than 3gb ram on a laptop being available.